# I want to use @ngneat/cashew with interceptor for cache HTTP request does it possible?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, interceptor

Please read the instruction of `@ngneat/cashew` before answering this question from here [**@ngneat/cashew**](https://github.com/ngneat/cashew)

The Idea is simple instead of doing this in `service` level like this,

```
this.httpClient.get<Posts>(`http://localhost:3000/posts/${id}`,{context:withCache()});
```

I want to make a global interceptor. Here is my code snippet,

```
# Config of Interceptor
{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CacheInterceptor, multi: true
 }
```

```
# Here is CacheInterceptor 

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const modifiedRequest = request.clone(
      {context: withCache()}
    );
    return next.handle(modifiedRequest);
  }
```

I want to do this because adding `{ context : withCache() }`  in every service's method is repetitive, otherwise in a existing project  it it too much time killer. That's why I want achive this via making a custom `Interceptor`. Does it possible to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that using the `skipInterceptorDeclaration: true`

Check out my [solution](https://github.com/ngneat/cashew/discussions/51#discussioncomment-3530161)